# Can't change color of SVG to white

Tags: html, css, svg, sass

In my Angular project I'm working on project where I use SVG to show some icons. Icons have default grey color and I want to change it to white when hovering on it. I try to change to red/green/yellow color it works, but when I try white color it not working.

Here is my HTML code

```html
<div class="user-name">
    <svg *ngIf="hasCopyToClipboard" width="10" height="12" viewBox="0 0 10 12"
         fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path opacity="0.5"
              d="M6.49997 0.500031H0.999995C0.449998 0.500031 0 0.950028 0 1.50003V7.99999C0 8.27499 0.224999 8.49999 0.499997 8.49999C0.774996 8.49999 0.999995 8.27499 0.999995 7.99999V2.00002C0.999995 1.72502 1.22499 1.50003 1.49999 1.50003H6.49997C6.77497 1.50003 6.99996 1.27503 6.99996 1.00003C6.99996 0.725029 6.77497 0.500031 6.49997 0.500031ZM6.79497 2.79502L9.20995 5.21001C9.39495 5.39501 9.49995 5.65 9.49995 5.915V10.5C9.49995 11.05 9.04995 11.5 8.49996 11.5H2.99498C2.44499 11.5 1.99999 11.05 1.99999 10.5L2.00499 3.50002C2.00499 2.95002 2.44999 2.50002 2.99998 2.50002H6.08497C6.34997 2.50002 6.60497 2.60502 6.79497 2.79502ZM6.49997 6H8.74996L5.99997 3.25002V5.50001C5.99997 5.775 6.22497 6 6.49997 6Z"
              fill="white"/>
    </svg>
    {{userData?.UserName}}
</div>
```

Here is my SCSS

```css
.user-name {
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding-left: 3px;

  svg {
    float: right;
    margin: 2px 0 2px 10px;
    cursor: pointer;

    :hover {
      fill: white;
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are setting the fill color on `:hover` directly on `svg`, while it should be on the `path` element, because the SVG path already has `fill="blue"`.

```css
svg:hover path { }
```

See below for an example as an extraction of your provided code.

```css
svg {
  margin: 2px 0 2px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

svg:hover path {
  fill: red;
}
```

```html
<svg width="10" height="12" viewBox="0 0 10 12" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                    <path opacity="0.5"
                                          d="M6.49997 0.500031H0.999995C0.449998 0.500031 0 0.950028 0 1.50003V7.99999C0 8.27499 0.224999 8.49999 0.499997 8.49999C0.774996 8.49999 0.999995 8.27499 0.999995 7.99999V2.00002C0.999995 1.72502 1.22499 1.50003 1.49999 1.50003H6.49997C6.77497 1.50003 6.99996 1.27503 6.99996 1.00003C6.99996 0.725029 6.77497 0.500031 6.49997 0.500031ZM6.79497 2.79502L9.20995 5.21001C9.39495 5.39501 9.49995 5.65 9.49995 5.915V10.5C9.49995 11.05 9.04995 11.5 8.49996 11.5H2.99498C2.44499 11.5 1.99999 11.05 1.99999 10.5L2.00499 3.50002C2.00499 2.95002 2.44999 2.50002 2.99998 2.50002H6.08497C6.34997 2.50002 6.60497 2.60502 6.79497 2.79502ZM6.49997 6H8.74996L5.99997 3.25002V5.50001C5.99997 5.775 6.22497 6 6.49997 6Z"
                                          fill="blue"/>
```

Comment: but when trying white color, it not working :/

Comment: @HovhannesGevorgyan `white` on `white` will never work.